# Modal open from a custom place

Tags: angularjs, dialog, popup, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

any ideas?

How to run the **MODAL** the way, 
that it's **visually** opening & closing **FROM** and **TO** the place where it was called/clicked?

Ideally Bootstrap modal with Bootstrap setup.
Thank you!

([example is here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog))

Comment: It is a broad question. Be specific, provide your code.

Comment: Why not just use the angular material dialog?

Comment: Are you talking about the animation of the modal while open/close?

Comment: Sorry for later reply. Yes I'm talking about the situation, where you click on the button and the modal window is showing up, like it's raising from that button. When closing, it's getting back to the button position.

Comment: Material dialog, then i need the angular, isn't it?
I have just bootstrap / minimal & fast setup. This feature i've found as very user friendly.